# Building a list from positional relationships between the elements

Tags: python, algorithm, list

How can I form a flat, ordered list from a set of items, each possibly with requirements that they appear before and/or after some other item in the list?

```
Sample input
-----------------------
3: before 5 and after 2
8: before 5
2: before 3
5: no constraint

Sample output
-------------
[2, 3, 8, 5]
```

Obviously, the general solution to this sort of problem is non-unique (consider the case of lots of elements with no constraints), which is fine - any result which meets the constraints will do.

I also know that there are lots of error cases here (duplicate elements, two elements which both want to be before each other, etc...). Right now I'm interested in the 'happy path' - I'll add error handling later.

Here are a few test cases in Python. They're far from comprehensive, but should be enough to give you the idea:

```
def test_some_unconstrained_elements():
    l = ListBuilder()
    l.add(1, after=None, before=None)
    l.add(7, after=None, before=None)
    assert set(l.to_list()) == {1, 7}

def test_element_which_should_appear_after_already_added_element():
    l = ListBuilder()
    l.add(5, after=None, before=None)
    l.add(3, after=5, before=None)
    assert l.to_list() == [5, 3]

def test_element_which_should_appear_after_element_added_later():
    l = ListBuilder()
    l.add(3, after=5, before=None)
    l.add(5, after=None, before=None)
    assert l.to_list() == [5, 3]

def test_element_which_should_appear_between_two_already_added_elements():
    l = ListBuilder()
    l.add(4, after=None, before=None)
    l.add(2, after=None, before=None)
    l.add(6, after=2, before=4)
    assert l.to_list() == [2, 6, 4]

def test_two_elements_either_side_of_new_element():
    l = ListBuilder()
    l.add(4, after=6, before=None)
    l.add(2, after=None, before=6)
    l.add(6, after=None, before=None)
    assert l.to_list() == [2, 6, 4]

def test_element_which_should_appear_after_missing_element():
    l = ListBuilder()
    l.add(4, after=6, before=None)
    assert l.to_list() == [4]

def test_two_elements_which_should_appear_after_the_same_element():
    l = ListBuilder()
    l.add(4, after=None, before=None)
    l.add(6, after=4, before=None)
    l.add(8, after=4, before=None)
    assert l[0] == 4
    assert set(l[1:]) == {6, 8}

def test_fully_constrained_short_list():
    l = ListBuilder()
    l.add(3, after=4, before=None)
    l.add(4, after=5, before=3)
    l.add(5, after=None, before=4)
    assert l.to_list() == [5, 4, 3]
```

NB. **This is not homework**. It's an actual problem I need to solve in real life (I'm working on [a test framework](https://github.com/benjamin-hodgson/Contexts); I'll be happy to elaborate on what I need it for), but I'm not clever enough for it :(

Comment: Is this `2: before 3             | 8` correct?

Comment: What have you got so far, aside from the test cases?

Comment: @rendon Apologies, I think my sample input/output table is formatted in a slightly misleading way. I'll change it.

Comment: You are using numbers in your example. Is sorting your list not an option?

Comment: @Dietrich: IRL it'll be a list of classes.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I spent a frustrating afternoon on the problem. I have tried a great variety of approaches: reading the input values into a linked list (the problem is more complex than that, as elements in the output may not appear _directly_ before or after the ones they request to be before/after); reading the input values into a tree (nope, there may be multiple pointers to a given element); adding the no-constraint ones to the output list first (no, further constraints may require them to swap over)...

Comment: This seems as a Topological sorting. This sorting is often used in project planning to arrange the activities. Am I Right?

Comment: You might be better sorting on the way out than the way in; as constraints may be violated later, you have to wait until you have all the items to order them (or discover you can't). You'll need a way to hold each object and its rules, dump them in in any order, then put all the thinking in when you get the list back to iterate over.

Comment: I think you have a faulty design assumption for your test framework.  Tests should never depend on one another.

Comment: @DmitryBeransky This algorithm is not for the tests themselves. I'm working on the issue of extensibility: users can define 'plugin' classes which define methods for the test runner to call into. However the order in which the runner calls the plugins matters, so users must be able to choose what comes before/after their plugin. I absolutely agree that tests should run independently!

Comment: @jonrsharpe I thought about that approach. The question is, how do you build the list in small steps while maintaining the invariant? What should you insert first? Adding unconstrained elements first doesn't work as future constraints may require them to move. Adding the 'most-constrained' elements first is tricky too - how do you determine which ones are the most constrained?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like a topological sort, so grab an implementation from somewhere (e.g. [here](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Topological_sort#Python)) and modify your data format to work with it.  For example:

```
def toposort2(data):
    # modified from http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Topological_sort#Python
    for k, v in data.items():
        v.discard(k) # Ignore self dependencies
    extra_items_in_deps = reduce(set.union, data.values()) - set(data.keys())
    data.update({item:set() for item in extra_items_in_deps})
    while True:
        ordered = set(item for item,dep in data.items() if not dep)
        if not ordered:
            break
        for x in sorted(ordered):
            yield x
        data = {item: (dep - ordered) for item,dep in data.items()
                if item not in ordered}
    if data:
        raise ValueError("a cyclic dependency exists")

def toposort_wrap(data):
    dep_dict = {}
    for d in data:
        for bef in d.get("before", ()):
            dep_dict.setdefault(bef, set()).add(d["value"])
        dep_dict.setdefault(d["value"], set()).update(d.get("after", ()))
    print dep_dict
    result = list(toposort2(dep_dict))
    return result
```

After which we have

```
>>> data = [dict(value=3, before=(5,), after=(2,)),
...         dict(value=8, before=(5,)),
...         dict(value=2, before=(3,)),
...         dict(value=5)]
>>> toposort_wrap(data)
{8: set([]), 2: set([]), 3: set([2]), 5: set([8, 3])}
[2, 8, 3, 5]
```

(Untested, so more proof-of-concept than anything else, but this is how I'd go about it.)

Comment: +1 for mentioning the benefits of grabbing an existing implementation.

Comment: I ended up using a different implementation of topological sorting (Wikipedia has two) because it seemed to suit the shape of my data better. But I wouldn't have known what to Google for without your answer. Thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 0):

Topological sort seems to be a good solution. The graph can look like that: each element of the list is node. If a goes before b, then there is a directed edge from b to a.